# Express req.cookie is undefined

Tags: node.js, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I'm am trying to set a cookie with a jwt in my express app.
I can set the cookie without any problem, developer tools say it is set, but when i try to get it by using req.cookie['cookie'] it shows as 'undefined' in the nodejs console.
I've read here and there and it seems that maybe there is a problem with the chrome developer tool.
here's how i set it.

```
res.cookie('authcookie', jwt)
```

here's how i'm trying to get i back

```
const authCookie = req.cookies['authcookie']
```

I am using cookieParser.

Can you help find out what can i do to show it? Thanks

Comment: Is req.cookies['authcookie'] undefined??

Comment: yes it says undefined, but the set-cookie response header shows that it was set

Comment: if you send a request with postman, is there problem still?

Comment: hey yes, it works with postman! what could it be?

Comment: OK i managed to get it working online but i have to enable third-party cookies, as the server of thi api is on another domain. Should i save it in localhost instead(the token i mean)? or there is a way to get this always working with cookies?

Comment: I don’t know‍♂️

Comment: ahahah :) ... in the end, i managed to get it wokring online but i had to allow third party cokie cause my frontend and backend are separated, i was spending to much time so i opted for localhost, i'll will come back to the issue some time in the future XD

Answer (score 0):

this works for me
use [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) as middleware in app.js

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use cookie-parser

nd second is that your user is logged in

you can also see cookies in the postman cookie section[If the cookie is not there then you have to generate a cookie first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2kDY.png)